# Image on UIBarButtonItem

Tags: iphone, ios4

In my iPhone application, I'm adding a toolbar on UINavigation controller as navigation bar do not take more then two bar buttons on it. 
So far .. I have successfully added the UIToolBar with three BarButtonItems on it. However I am not able to display an image on BarButtonItems.

Can any one tell me .. how to add image on UIToolBar BarButtonItems? Where ToolBar is already added on nav controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set a custom view for the UIBarButtonItem, something like this

```
    UIBarButtonItem *barButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] init];

    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    UIImage *yourImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"yourImage.png"];
    [button setImage:yourImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(yourButtonAction) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    [barButton setCustomView:button];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = barButton;
    [barButton release];
```

Comment: Thanks! I tested this code, this is working fine when i create a new application. But anyhow it's not working in my project. and it's showing no bug.. please suggest!

Comment: have you use navigation controller base view or present modal view

Comment: Navigation Controller and i am hiding it into the viewWillApper .. [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];

Comment: GhostRider, Do u have any idea where i'm mistaken?

Answer (score 0):

```
   button = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image]];
button.action = @selector(myaction);
button.target = self;
```

Try this.

Comment: I added this code into my viewWillAppear method ..where i am hiding the NavigationBar. Is this a problem of not showing image??